# Content provider authorization issue in Android app

Tags: android

In becon Android app what should be placed in MyContentProvider class as the sample app mentions in comment line as "Implement this to initialize your content provider on startup".

Facing the issue

> E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for
>   com.mobstac.beaconstacexample.provider
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL
>   content://com.mobstac.beaconstacexample.provider/place/

Comment: Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: Can't say anything without seeing the code. Is provider declared in AndroidManifest file in <application> tag.

Comment: yes, i have declared provider in AndroidManifest as 

  <provider
                android:name="<my package name>.MyContentProvider"
                android:authorities="com.mobstac.beaconstacexample.provider"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false"
                android:multiprocess="true"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                android:syncable="true" />                                                                But declared  inside the activity  where becon statred